# Django ORM: Tried to do inner join with foreign key but causes FieldError

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, inner-join

I am new to django orm. 
I've tables look like this.

```
class Product(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=60)

class ProductOption(models.Model):
   id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
   product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

I would like to query productoption id that related to product. I made query like this to do inner join.

```
Query = Product.select_related(‘product_id’).filter(name='a')
```

And it gaves me error message saying

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'product_id'. Choices are: (none)
```

I want to know if there is something wrong in models or query.

Comment: What is exactly your expected output?

Comment: @scharette I would like to get all product objcects and get productOptions that connected to product_id

Comment: _ productOptions that connected to product_i_ I don't understand what you mean ? you want to get all of the productOptions for one particular `Product` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.prefetch_related)

```
Product.objects.filter(name='a').prefetch_related('productoption_set')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you query a related object. Since you used a foreign key and if I understand correctly, you probably want to use something like this:

```
 Product.objects.filter(name='a').productoption_set.all()
```